# Why Can't I Change My Vote After a Comment?

Tags: discussion, locked-votes

I recently down-voted an answer because I believed it contained out-of-date information.  I then left a comment saying as much.

The answerer responded to my comment with one of their own, and it clarified that their answer was in fact not out of date.

So, I tried to fix my vote, but when I did I saw "You last voted on this answer 2 days ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

I get the idea of the lock, but shouldn't a new comment be counted the same as an edit?

Comment: Commenting is not editing.

Comment: Obviously, but it's adding new information which could impact someone's vote, and the whole idea of the lock was to prevent vote changes unless new information was added.

Comment: Commenting does not add new information to either a question or an answer.

Comment: Commenting is *just* commentation.

Comment: You make this a lot easier when you link to the answer.  I think I found it, I compensated for the downvote.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377065/can-we-allow-changing-a-vote-after-some-valuable-comments-have-been-added

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments are not part of the question or the answer proper, and so no, they are not counted the same. If the question or answer as it has been written is unclear or may be interpreted to be wrong, then the problem with the Q or A remains, despite any possible clarification that may be found within a comment. If not, if it's all a misinterpretation on your part, then perhaps better would be to comment first before voting (easy to say in retrospect).

One possible solution is for the OP (or you) to edit the answer and include any necessary clarification within it.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are not meant to have the same meaning as edits. When you add a comment, it literally says:

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.

By this description, they are not meant to be permanent. If it's important enough, it can be edited into the answer, at which point you will be able to undo your vote.