# Downvotes should be reversible for more than 6 hours

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

When you downvote, you cannot revert your decision after 6 hours (or 8 hours, not sure atm) as long as the answer was not edited. But this is too short and wrong.
Recently I had a case where I downvoted an answer because I thought the answer would be a bad programming style. Later it turned out, that it is correct in this one single case.

See here: ["Avoid passing null as the view root" warning when inflating view for use by AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404951/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-warning-when-inflating-view-for-use-by-ale/26596164#comment94222428_26596164)

I wanted to revert my downvote, but it's not possible after 6 hours, which is too short. It should be at least half a week or a week. Why. Because the one I downvoted could reply and explain why his answer was still correct. Consider that people are not here around the clock. They don't even live in the same country or on the same continent, so 6 hours are far too little. Some people are not here even for days.

Comment: are you sure it's 6h? I think it's much less, few minutes

Comment: up and down votes are locked after 5 minutes. A post needs an edit after that to unlock the vote.

Comment: see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256606/cannot-change-vote-even-though-the-post-has-been-edited and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit/251233#251233

Comment: @rene Ok, there is a possible explanation why this is so, but then, the downvote should subtract a higher amount than you get via upvote or something like that to avoid "tactical downvotes".

Comment: @Bevor Tactical downvotes seems a separate, unrelated concern to the one you discuss in your Q here. A tactical downvote is likely to *not* be reversed, regardless of the lock-in period, precisely because its tactical, and serving different motivations. As for the problem you discuss in your Q... the answer you downvoted has 150 upvotes. Your downvote didn’t even make a dent in it. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: @Bevor given we need moar users that cast downvotes, let's not make it even more unattractive to do so ...

Comment: @DanBron "tactical downvote is likely to not be reversed"??? The whole point of tactical downvote is to push other answers down *without losing any reputation*. One have to remove downvotes to get full benefit.

Answer (score 7):

You downvoted for a reason you thought was good, then realized you were mistaken. To prevent others from making that same mistake, edit some form of the answerer's explanation into the answer.

*Voilà*, your downvote is unlocked.

Comment: One may try to suggest to just add comment instead of edit to unblock votes but that considered bad idea https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377604/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-after-a-comment.

Comment: In this particular case, there actually was already a comment pointing out the issue that Bevor downvoted over.